# Javah -stubs isn't generating c stub

Tags: java, compiler-errors, javah

System: I am using Windows 8.1, Eclipse Juno Service Release 2.

OK, for starters I have tried compiling my project using Eclipse and that works.  My class is called *CConnecter* and the code is:

```
public class CConnecter {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("C:\\Users\\Chris\\workspace\\Black Light\\bin\\Connecter");
    }

    public native void start();

    public native void setValues(int i, int j, int k);

    public native void stop();
}
```

I tried using the command line command *"cd C:\Users\Chris\workspace\Black Light\bin"*.  (my project name is *Black Light*.)  Then I ran *"javah CConnecter"*.  This successfully generated the c header file (CConnecter.h).  When I run *"javah -stubs CConnecter"*, nothing happens.

I would like some help figuring out what the problem is.

*Console output:*
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wOcA.png

I have also tried with tested and performing code from other sources such as **Sun**'s and **JavaWorld**'s Tutorials and they don't work either.

More information:
When I type *"javah --help"*, *"javah -h"*, or *"javah -?"* to access the help, *"-stubs"* doesn't appear.  I don't know why this is.  I have also tried doing this process with **Java 7** and **Java 8** newest versions, and neither worked.

Comment: What does javah says?

Comment: javah doesn't generate stubs for me either, but it does generate headers.

Comment: @xav, there is no output.

Comment: It hasn't done that for some years as far as I know. Probably a good idea, as there is a great risk of overwriting your code.

Comment: @EJP what are you referring to?

Comment: If you generate the .c file with javah, then edit your code into it, then you decide to change the method signature so you rerun javah, you risk losing the code you wrote.

Comment: @EJP OK. Thanks for the help.  My main problem is that "javah" doesn't even run!  There is no javah command in the compiler.